# Why does lazy load work locally but not on netlify for hugo static website?

Tags: lazy-loading, netlify, hugo

I have implemented lazy load and render hooks using the Hugo guide. However, it works locally but does not work when deployed to Netlify.

Why is that happening?

My markdown is such:

```
![Title](path to image "Title")
```

In chrome dev tools it renders as:

```
<img src="path" alt="Title" loading="lazy" width="100%" height="auto">
```

My render template is placed here: themes\red\layouts_default_markup\render-image.html

The template code is:

```
<!-- layouts/_default/_markup/render-image.html -->
{{ $img := imageConfig (add "/content" (.Destination | safeURL)) }}

<img
  src="{{ .Destination | safeURL }}"
  alt="{{ .Text }}"
  loading="lazy"
  width="100%"
  height="auto"
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue. In netlify I explicitly set the hugo version to a very new release as below and the problem was solved.

[image]